# ¿Cómo resolver una ecuación con raíz cuadrada utilizando sympy?

Tags: python

Trato de resolver una ecuación que contiene una raíz cuadrada mediante expresiones regulares:

```
'√({}x + {}) = √{}' : 'sqrt({}*x + {}) - sqrt({})'
```

Por medio de `eval()` resuelvo la variable que sustituye la expresión regular a evaluar:

```
expr = expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,w,x,y,z) 
eq1 = Eq(eval(expr, {"x":x}), 0)
```

Y directamente no tendría que tener problema, pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined
```

Importé correctamente `from math import sqrt` y `from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve`, pero no entiendo por qué me arroja dicho error de definir
`sqrt`.

Código completo:

```
from random import randint, choice
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
from math import sqrt
import re

archivo = open(r'C:\Users\youna\Desktop\Ejercicio8.6.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

result=[]
for i in range(8000):

  fmts = {
  '√({}x + {}) = √{}' : 'sqrt({}*x + {}) - sqrt({})'
    }

  a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,w,x,y,z = [randint(1, 15) for _ in range(12)]
  view_expr, expr = choice(list(fmts.items()))
  expr = expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,w,x,y,z)

  view_expr = view_expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,w,x,y,z)

  x = symbols('x')
  eq1 = Eq(eval(expr, {"x":x}), 0)
  sol = eval(str(expr))
  sol = (f'{sol} ')
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a resolver este problema? De antemano muchas gracias! Saludos.

Comment: Python por defecto no tiene una función para calcular la raíz cuadrada, tienes que usar alguna librería (Ya sea por ejemplo `math` que es parte de las librerías estandar de Python o por ejemplo `numpy`). Si intentas con `math` puedes hacerlo como `from math import sqrt` y funcionará, veo en la parte final que lo intentaste hacer, no se si es error al escribir la pregunta pero escribiste "form", es `from` y escribiste `sqer` y es `sqrt`. revisa que lo hayas escrito bien.

Comment: Error de dedo, corregido en la pregunta, muchas gracias, pero en el código escribí `from math import sqrt` correctamente y aún así me sigue arrojando el mismo error

Comment: Hice una prueba rápida únicamente con `sqrt(9)` y funciona correctamente. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Comment: Editado, código añadido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es porque cuando utilizas `eval()` estas pasando las variables globales como argumento y te hace falta definir `sqrt` en el diccionario ([Artículo de ayuda](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)).

**Nota:** Como estas utilizando `sympy` es mejor utilizar `sqrt` de `sympy` en lugar de `math` ya que si utlizas la de `math` al tener símbolos vas a obtener el siguiente error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float

Ejemplo completo (Cambié el número de iteraciones a 5 y agregué un `print(sol)` para verificar el funcionamiento):

```
from random import randint, choice
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, sqrt
import re

#archivo = open(r'C:\Users\youna\Desktop\Ejercicio8.6.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

result=[]
for i in range(5):
    fmts = {
    '√({}x + {}) = √{}' : 'sqrt({}*x + {}) - sqrt({})'
    }

    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,w,x,y,z = [randint(1, 15) for _ in range(12)]
    view_expr, expr = choice(list(fmts.items()))
    expr = expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,w,x,y,z)

    view_expr = view_expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,w,x,y,z)

    x = symbols('x')
    eq1 = Eq(eval(expr, {'x':x, 'sqrt': sqrt}), 0)
    sol = eval(str(expr))
    sol = (f'{sol} ')
    print(sol)
```

**Edición:** Si quitas el diccionario de variables globales no hace falta ni definir el símbolo `x` ni la función `sqrt`, de esta forma:

```
eq1 = Eq(eval(expr), 0)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @HeytalePazguato, funciona correctamente, pero tengo una inquietud, prácticamente me arroja lo mismo que la segunda expresión regular a evaluar. Es decir, es como si copiara y pegara directamente tal cuál en el resultado la expresión `sqrt({}*x + {}) - sqrt({})` pero con números, algo así: `sqrt(15*x + 9) - 2*sqrt(3)`, no se sustityue la `x`, no me arroja ningún entero, fracción, etc., ¿a qué se debe esto?

Comment: Eso es porque `sympy` trabaja con matemática simbólica, si deseas que lo resuelva haz `print(solve(sol))` eso devolverá los resultados numéricos. O no se si te refieras a eso, a resolver la expresión. O ¿Qué te gustaría que hiciera?

Comment: O si quieres que se vea como una ecuación si quitas las 3 últimas líneas y pones `display(eval(expr))` aparece como ecuación (Por lo menos en una prueba rápida en Jupyterlab)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona correctamente